# Lower bound on the sum of divisor function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It there a lower bound on the sum of divisors function? More specifically is there a "simple" function  $f(n)$  such that $\sigma(n) \ge f(n)$ for all $n$ large enough?

Answer (score 2):

For any $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$ the set of (positive) divisors of $n$ contains at least $1$ and $n$ itself, so one has $\sigma(n)\geq 1+n$. This is an optimal lower bound, since $\sigma(p)=p+1$ for a prime $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. For 
example, $f(n)\equiv 0$ or even $f(n)=n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

The best function is actually $f(n)=n+1$ which holds iff $n$ is prime.
Since there are infinitely many primes you can't expect anything better for $n$ large enough.
Ramanujan under the assumption of Riemann hypothesis has shown that $\sigma(n)<e^{\gamma}n{\log\log}n$ for $n$ sufficiently large.
Unfortunately, $\sigma(n)$ does not have a certain rate of growth.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can prove, that for $n>1$ we have:

$\sigma(n) \ge \sqrt{\frac{2\sum_{d<e,d|n,e|n}{de}}{\sum{p|n,p \text{ prime }}{\frac{p \log(p)}{p-1}-\log(p-1)}}}$

Although this formula is not "simple" it seems to be true and a good lower bound if the number $n$ is "highly composed" (better than $n+1$).